# In "You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink", why is the horse a male?

Tags: etymology, idioms

In the proverb "You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink", why is the horse a male? Is there an origin/backstory, similarly to how boats are considered female?

Also, I think "...make him drink..." is the original, rather than "...make it drink...". Does anyone know if this, or the opposite, is correct?

Edit: I found from my research that Old English Homilies, written in 1175, might have been where the proverb came from (the exact reference was "Hwa is thet mei thet hors wettrien the him self nule drinken"). However, this doesn't seem to explain why the horse is referred to as "him" in the proverb.

Thanks!

Comment: Not all ships – except [**man-of-war**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/man-of-war) and [**merchantman**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/merchantman) and possibly others.

Comment: A female horse is called a "mare"?? And perhaps male animals have the fame of being stubborn?

Comment: I wonder whether there was any preference for male horses either for work or carriage. I know in horse racing they usually remark if a mare is the winner. Alternatively, was the pronoun “it” in use at the time? Was “him” just common gender?  I can’t answer because I don’t know.

Comment: The male was used as the default generic long before PCness was championed. @Weather Vane Then there was 'There's the _Duke of Gloucester_  – she's a lovely engine'. And Thomas.

Comment: FYI, Elephind newspaper database searches covering newspapers in Australia and the US find 854 matches for "but you can't make him drink," dating to 1858; 61 matches for "but you can't make it drink," dating to 1864; and 2 matches for "but you can't make her drink," dating to 1920 (the first of those two instances refers to a chicken rather than to a horse, but the second, from 1931, refers to a horse). I didn't check the individual results for duplicate matches—but even if they are fairly numerous, the overall preference for "him" over "it" is quite substantial.

Comment: @Sven Yargs Thanks for introducing the resource to us. It seems that what you found confirms that "him" was the more popular version of the proverb, leading me to believe it may have come before the "it" version.

Comment: As it's usually pronounced in English, the final phrase is /mekəm'drɪŋk/, which could be transcribed as _make him drink_ or _make them drink_. Both are grammatical, both mean the same thing. Differences between them are social and political, not linguistic.

Comment: As a followup to John Lawler's interesting comment, I ran an Elephind search for "but you can't make them drink"—and found two instances (dating to 1961) of the phrase used in connection with "horses" and three instances (dating to 1983) used in connection with "a horse." A similar search for "but you can't make 'em drink" yields three matches (dating to 1980) involving "a horse" and one instance (from 1929) involving "lead[ing] the U.S. gentry to the trough."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In basic terms, A horse was a male and a mare was female.

From [The Middle English Compendium](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED21229/track?counter=2&search_id=4126200):

Hors (n.) 1.(a) A horse [often presumably = (b)]; (b) an adult male horse; male ~.

c1400(?c1382) Wycl.Lincoln.(Bod 647)231 : As a horce unrubbed, þat haves a sore back, wynses when he is oght touched or rubbed on his rugge.

Although "[mare](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED27420/track?counter=7&search_id=4126200)" also meant "horse of any gender and type:

> 1. A riding horse, a steed; also, any beast of burden; also, cattle, livestock, pastured domesticated animals;
>
> Etymology OE mēares, mēare, etc. (infl. forms of mearh, *merh 'horse') & WS mȳ̆re, A *mēre 'mare'.

it was later used chiefly for the female horse:

> "(c1300) Havelok (LdMisc 108)2504 : Þei garte bringe þe mere sone..And bunden him rith at **hire** tayl.

> ?a1425(c1400) Mandev.(1) (Tit C.16)167/21,29 : And men putten a mare besyde him with **hire** fole & an **hors** sadeled & brydeled..

Comment: Thank you, @Greybeard! Very clear and detailed answer.